# Themeing a selector drawable on pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-theme, attr, android-selector

I have a `selector` item in my app that is used as the background color of a listview row. The point is that the row changes color when it is being clicked / touched.

The selector therefore uses two drawables, one for the pressed state and one regular. 
File: `rowbgselector.xml` in folder `res/color`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rowbg_shape_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rowbg_shape" />
</selector>
```

The two drawables referenced are defined in `res/drawable` as simple rectangle shapes with a solid color:

File `rowbg_shape.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/row_bg"/>
</shape>
```

File `rowbg_shape_selected.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

This works on Lollipop devices but fails on anything pre-Lollipop with an error that doesn't say much:
`Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/rowbg_shape_selected.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02006c`

I believe the issue is that this is a bug that was fixed in Lollipop, see here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251

The problem is that I'm trying to reference `attr/colorAccent` which is of course defined in my themes. I have several themes with different colors which the user can choose from and `attr/colorAccent` is different in all of them. However it seems due to this bug on pre-Lollipop you can't reference an attribute like this in a selector...

What are my alternative options? The only option I can think of is creating a separate selector xml file for every theme, and add something like `attr/bg_selector` which then references the correct selector file for each theme. That will take me ages and further it would be a ton of work to change anything for this selector (what if I want to make the color slightly darker or lighter later, I'd have to go through all those files...).

Is there no other option?

Comment: I did something similar here. probably this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717352/selector-layer-list-and-shape-bitmap-in-the-same-xml

Comment: I'm not sure if that's relevant, all your colors etc are static. I want to reference an attribute so that I can change its value in my (many) themes, but that is not possible in a selector (at least before Lollipop).

Comment: why you use `?attr/colorAccent`, insteadd of something like ´@color/...´?

Comment: Because that allows me to specify a different color for each theme. If I use @color/... I have to hardcode a color and cannot change it between themes. Note I use `@color/row_bg` for the non-pressed state, because all themes use the same color for non-pressed (row_bg, which is white), but for the pressed state I want the color to depend on the theme.

Comment: Or.. create `StateListDrawable`s at runtime.

Comment: have you found any workaround on this? Seems that `?attr/colorAccent` still doesn't work inside <selectors>

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: I'm afraid you are correct, there is no other way to solve this issue pre-Lollipop.

I came across this question searching for an answer to a related but different issue with one of the built-in selectors (namely `activatedBackgroundIndicator` as it relates to `colorControlActivated` and `colorAccent`). In my case, a hacky workaround was to define a color resource in the shared library and then define a color resource of the same name in each app. I don't think there is something like that for themes that is supported pre-Lollipop.